# angularJS custom directive unable to show scope string variable

Tags: angularjs

Inside my custom directive validation_message_tag.js, I have several strings assigned to `$scope` when `data` is updated.

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //todo: validation not working
    $scope.success = newValue ? newValue.success : ''
    $scope.info = newValue ? newValue.info : ''
    $scope.warning = newValue ? newValue.warning : ''
    $scope.error = newValue ? newValue.error : ''
}, true)
```

And this is my HTML page

```
<div class="validation-message-tag" ng-show="ctrl.$touched && ctrl.message">
  <p ng-show="success" class="validation-success">{{success}}</p>
  <p ng-show="warning" class="validation-warning">{{warning}}</p>
  <p ng-show="info" class="validation-info">{{info}}</p>
  <p ng-show="error" class="validation-error">{{error}}</p>
</div>
```

When I set a breakpoint inside the $watch, variables did get assigned properly. But no message is shown on the screen.

Comment: are those all values are `boolean` 's?

Comment: no, all values are strings

Comment: which should be evaluated to true if length > 0

Comment: then it should be `$scope.success = newValue.success.length > 0` same applied for other flag

Comment: newValue.success can be undefined

Comment: why is newValue.success not evaluating to true false?

Comment: Vcould you create plubkr/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using ng-show for validation anymore.
the angular team recommend using ngMessages for validation.

here's a plunk which might be useful to you.
http://run.plnkr.co/Mw8BG27oyjfMY2rT/

Comment: You'll have to convert to 1.3 version of angular if youre using an older version.